# How to resolve pipe dead-lock in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pipe, deadlock

I am trying to emulate UNIX command line pipes in a Ruby-only solution that uses multiple cores. Eventually, the records piped from command to command will be Ruby objects marshaled using msgpack. Unfortunately, the below code hangs after the first dump command. I suspect a pipe deadlock, but I fail to resolve it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'parallel'
require 'msgpack'
require 'pp'

class Pipe
  def initialize
    @commands = []
  end

  def add(command, options = {})
    @commands << Command.new(command, options)

    self
  end

  def run
    @commands.each_cons(2) do |c_in, c_out|
      reader, writer = IO.pipe

      c_out.input = MessagePack::Unpacker.new(reader)
      c_in.output = MessagePack::Packer.new(writer)
    end

    Parallel.each(@commands, in_processes: @commands.size) { |command| command.run }

    self
  end

  class Command
    attr_accessor :input, :output

    def initialize(command, options)
      @command = command
      @options = options
      @input   = nil
      @output  = nil
    end

    def run
      send @command
    end

    def cat
      @input.each_with_index { |record, i| @output.write(record).flush } if @input

      File.open(@options[:input]) do |ios|
        ios.each { |record| @output.write(record).flush } if @output
      end
    end

    def dump
      @input.each do |record|
        puts record
        @output.write(record).flush if @output
      end
    end
  end
end

p = Pipe.new
p.add(:cat, input: "foo.tab").add(:dump).add(:cat, input: "table.txt").add(:dump)
p.run
```

Comment: `send @command` what is this?

Comment: similar to method(@command).call - if @command is :cat, then method cat is called.